# Have read-only Lua script executed against read replicas in a Redis cluster

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I have:

1. A Redis cluster with primary nodes and read replicas.
2. Lua scripts that write data (keys).
3. Lua scripts that only read data.

I want to have the read-only Lua scripts executed against replicas in my Redis cluster. How can I do that?

Best as I can tell, the [ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED option](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/ReadFrom-Settings) only works for read commands, i.e. GET or [SCAN](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Redis-Cluster).

I am using the Spring Data Redis library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Eval flags](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/eval-intro/#eval-flags):

> Normally, when you run an Eval script, the server does not know how it accesses the database. By default, Redis assumes that all scripts read and write data. However, starting with Redis 7.0, there's a way to declare flags when creating a script in order to tell Redis how it should behave.

with the flag `no-writes`: this flag indicates that the script only reads data but never writes.

```
#!lua flags=no-writes
```

More information about [Read-only scripts](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/#read-only_scripts).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that, thanks for sharing. Is this a flag that I can just include at the top of my Lua script, or do I need to invoke the register_function?

Comment: Read-only scripts can be executed either by adding the no-writes flag to the script or by executing the script with one of the read-only script command variants: EVAL_RO, EVALSHA_RO, or FCALL_RO. Remember to check that your Redis version is >= 7.0.